# Attribute in MBean is different from the one received by web app

Tags: java, spring, jmx, managed-bean, visualvm

I have a service that's can be accessed via jconsole/Visual VM.

```
@ManagedResource
public class MyService
{
  private String foo;

  @ManagedAttribute
  public void setFoo(String newVal) { this.foo = newVal; }

  @ManagedAttribute
  public String getFoo() { return this.foo; }

  //some other things here that access foo
}
```

But looks like the value of `foo` received by the web app controller doesn't always match the value I get when I click getFoo() in either jconsle or visual VM.
Also, the debugger shows me that the value my controller get is not what I see in jconsole.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But looks like the value of foo received by the web app controller doesn't always match the value I get when I click getFoo() in either jconsle or visual VM. Also, the debugger shows me that the value my controller get is not what I see in jconsole.

I'm not sure but I suspect that the value `foo` is not being properly memory synchronized between the various threads.  You should make `foo` be `volatile` if it being updated by a different thread than the one displaying the value -- or put up with JMX being out of date.

```
private volatile String foo;
```

Certainly the JMX request is being made from a different thread that your web-app would be handled by.  I would have thought, however, that the debugger would not have had the problem.

**Edit:**

After some back and forth I asked if it was possible that 2 instances of the `MyService` class were getting created/used.  @abcXYZ adding something like `System.out.println("getting foo in " + System.identityHashCode(this) + " = " + foo);` to the getter and setter methods which showed that there *were* actually 2 different instances of the class for some reason.
So the JMX thread was looking at one while the web app was using the other.  Ouch.

Comment: Totally forgot!! I'll try that. Thanks!!

Comment: By the debugger, I meant the debugger for the web app. NOT for the jmx. I'd be even more freaked out if the value from debugger for the web app matches the jmx and my web app shows otherwise.

Comment: too bad. it doesn't work for me. :(
I make `foo` `volatile` and still, the value in the jmx is still different from that in my web app

Comment: Any chance there are 2 instances of this MyService getting published @abcXYZ?  How about some printf (or logger) debugging here and be sure to print _which_ MyService instance you are doing.  Something like `System.out.println("getting foo in " + System.identityHashCode(this) + " = " + foo);`

Comment: Yeah I checked that. Print out the value of toString() on both instance. Same memory address.

Comment: Wow.  I'm about out of ideas.  Is there a chance that something in the view is getting and then setting the value back or something?  Can you log each of the calls to the getter _and_ the setter @abcXYZ?

Comment: I'm absolutely positively sure that no, there's not any thing that could possibly change that value. :(

Comment: Shoot!! Now the 2 instances seem to be different. `toString()` on the to instances gave me 2 different values:
 MyService@31ea681 and MyService@267279d3

Comment: So looks like the 2 instances are different. But I thought it's supposed to be the same.

Comment: Yeah I suspected something like that @abcXYZ.  Btw, that's not a "memory address" nor does it have to be unique.  Just for the record.  It's the instance hashCode is usually unique.  :-)

Comment: yeah i too much C stuff in my head. Anyways, so that really what happened. We had multiple instances running.